Why does URLCache require diskCapacity & memoryCapacity to be much greater than the response to cache it?
I have the following code.
let customCache: URLCache = {
    let cacheSizeMemory = 512 * 1024 * 1024
    let cacheSizeDisk = 512 * 1024 * 1024
    return URLCache(memoryCapacity: cacheSizeMemory, diskCapacity: cacheSizeDisk, diskPath: "serverTest")
}()

let customSession: URLSession = {
    // Create a custom URLSessionConfiguration
    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    sessionConfiguration.urlCache = customCache
    sessionConfiguration.requestCachePolicy = .useProtocolCachePolicy

    // Create a custom URLSession with the configuration
    let customSession = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
    return customSession
}()

Here are a few of the headers for my response:
< content-length: 93828673
< cache-control: public, max-age=300

I expect because of those headers the device to cache the response for 5 minutes. However that isn't what is happening.
Now when I change these variables to the following the cache does work:
let cacheSizeMemory = 512 * 1024 * 1024 * 5
let cacheSizeDisk = 512 * 1024 * 1024 * 5

This makes absolutely no sense to me because the response is only 93,828,673 bytes, which is far less than the maximum cache size of 536,870,912 bytes.
Does Apple set some type of buffer or something where a single response can only take up x% of the cache or something like that? I can't find any documentation that would suggest that, but it's the only explanation I can think of.

The documentation is not jumping out at me, but IIRC it historically wouldn’t cache responses that take up more than 10% of the cache. I’m guessing this is so one single response doesn’t wipe out too many cached responses in one fell swoop.

@Rob Super interesting. I wish Apple documented that. Someone also shared this article with me that says it's 5%. Would be nice if Apple was more clear about this.

I hear you. But, Apple tends not to document these sorts of parameters, probably to avoid painting themselves into a corner by making a formal contract with us in the documentation. The other example that jumps to mind is the timeout for background tasks which was 10 minutes, then quietly changed to 3 minutes a few years later, and then, again, quietly changed to 30 seconds a few years after that. Still, URLCache really should have property to indicate this parameter is, but there is not, AFAIK.

The disk cache 5% bit actually is mentioned in the documentation, albeit in the NSURLConnection documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlconnectiondatadelegate/1414834-connection?language=objc
